# HashMap Sharing object issue

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having the issue with the HashMaps, sharing the object. All the nested HashMaps have the same values. How do I overcome this issue? How do I create the HashMaps so they are independent from one another?

This below is my DTO, my first Integer object is going to range from 0-11, representing the months. The String represents country codes (i.e, "GB"), and the second Integer represents total amount of people. Meaning that value will be added to.

```
public class ClientsByMonth {
private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> res2015 = new HashMap<>();
```

Below is Where I am trying to create the HashMaps. I am putting 0 to all first before I start adding values to them because certain months don't have any value but I need it to be 0. Obviously the below is not working.

```
public class CBMSetter {    
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> resHashMap = new HashMap<>();             


 HashMap<String, Integer>[] byCountry = new HashMap[12];

String[] countrys = {"GB ", "PT ", "ES ", "BE ", "IE ", "FR ", "DE ", "CH ", "IR ", "NL ", "   ", "Others"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        byCountry[i] = new HashMap<>();
        for(int k = 0; k < 12; k++){
           byCountry[i].put(countrys[k], 0);
        }
    }

   for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
     *** resHashMap.put(i, new HashMap(byCountry[i]));
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
      **clientsBM.get(i).preSetRes( new HashMap(resHashMap));
   }
```

** is where the DTO exists
*** edited

Comment: Why not create a Java class to hold a number and a string? And let that be the value of the map? A nested Hashmap seems like a waste of resources for something this simple

Comment: resHashMap.put(i, new HashMap(byCountry[0])); you have hardcoded byCountry[0], is this fine ?

Comment: Along with my previous point, the outer Hashmap isn't needed. Your key is an index, so you should use an Arraylist

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean I should use another DTO?

Comment: @Awadesh I am using byCountry somewhere else also. I have not showed it here for simplicity reasons. Each byCountry(0-11) are already being used.

Comment: The proper acronym I would use is POJO, but sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code, all the nested HashMaps have the same values. Because in this loop, you are putting `byCountry[0]` in `resHashMap`.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
  resHashMap.put(i, new HashMap(byCountry[0]));
 }
```

So solution is try by replacing `byCountry[0]` with `byCountry[i]`

Comment: I am using byCountry somewhere else also. I have not showed it here for simplicity reasons. Each byCountry(0-11) are already being used. Should I create another array of Hashmaps like byCountry? Is there not a better way?

Comment: for this purpose you should use POJO , that is better option, or you can fetch the updated data where you are using byCountry[0])

Comment: @ Awadash & @ cricket_007 : I am trying to create this POJO object but then I need to create a HashMap inside of it to keep the different countries and there values for that particular month. Is that the best way?